# How to use the attribute(column) inherited from parent entity in JPQL when using Single Table Strategy for ORM/JPA

Tags: jpa, orm, jpql, single-table-inheritance

I have three class: User, Admin, NormalUser

Admin and NormalUser extends User Class and I use Single Table Strategy for inheritance when mapped to derby db table and I found out there will be error if I write a named query using inherited attribute in NormalUser class. More information can be referred from below code:

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorColumn;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorType;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="user_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("Null")
@Table(name="ALLUSER")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByAccount", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.account = :account")
})
public class User implements Serializable{
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String account;
    private String password;
    private String userType;
    
    public User() {
        super();
    }
    public User(String account, String password) {
        super();
        this.account = account;
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "account")
    public String getAccount() {
        return account;
    }
    public void setAccount(String account) {
        this.account = account;
    }
    
    @Column(name = "password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    @Column(name = "user_type", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    public String getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }
    public void setUserType(String userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return account;
    }
}

package entity;


import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;



@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Normal")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "NormalUser.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM NormalUser u")
})
public class NormalUser extends User implements Serializable{
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    //private String account;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private LinkedHashSet<Customer> customers;
    
    public NormalUser() {
        super();
    }
    

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="user", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}) //delete user will delete all customer
    public LinkedHashSet<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return customers;
    }

    public void setCustomers(LinkedHashSet<Customer> customers) {
        this.customers = customers;
    }
    
//  @Column(name = "account")
//  //have to override in order to get account to use
//  public String getAccount() {
//      return account;
//  }
//  
//  public void setAccount(String account) {
//      this.account = account;
//  }
}
```

If I write a named query using normal user's inherited attribute:

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Past;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c order by c.customerID desc")
    ,@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByUser", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.normalUser.account = :account")
})
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int customerID;
    private Industry customerIndustryType;
    private String customerName;
    private Address customerAddress;
    private String customerNationality;
    private Date customerAddedDate;
    private Double customerDiscountRate;
    private String customerScale;
    private List<Contact> customerContacts;
    private NormalUser normalUser;
    //getter and setter omited .....
}
```

Errors will be thrown when running it and it is apparently related to this query for accessing parent attribute:
[image: screenshot of error information]

Actually, I also try criteria API and it also failed:

```
//          customers = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Customers.findByAccount", Customer.class).setParameter("account", role).getResultList();
//          CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
//          CriteriaQuery<Customer> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Customer.class);
//          Root<Customer> c = criteriaQuery.from(Customer.class);
//          criteriaQuery.select(c).where(builder.equal(c.get("normalUser").get("account"), role)); //(p.get("price"), budget));//danger4
//          Query query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);     
//          //List<Property> properties = query.getResultList();
//          customers =  query.getResultList();
```

So How can I use the parent object's attribute? It should not be like this. If I extends the class, I will have all the inherited attributes, isn't it?

---------------------------------------------Update-----------------------------

The inherited attribute can be used in JPQL. It is just that we have to always remember to check the getter name when you annotation on it, which is what is resolved in JPQL.
Hope future visitors remember to pay attention to details.
LOL, The biggest bug comes from the easiest mistake.
The good thing is that due to this error, I have to access customers via user.getCustomers() since it is bidirectional. As a result, I learn a lot to maintain bidirectional relationship.

Comment: Is `Customer.normalUser` annotated by `@XxxToOne`? If not, it probably gets treated as a basic `Serializable` column, so of course you cannot query its properties, inherited or otherwise

Comment: @crizzis You literally save my day. Though I have added the annotation, you still remind me to check the getter in Customers and I find out the getter is named getUser(This is a long story because user is a keyword and the naming is changed many times). Since getter name is used to resolved in jpql, it cannot find normalUser but user. Now i feel soooo stupid. It is so true that the biggest bug comes from the easiest mistake. Anyway, thanks.